# How do I restore Exchange 2003 public folder into 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2003, backup-restoration

Our box running Windows Server 2003 and Exchange Server 2003 was recently replaced with a box running Windows Server 2008 and Exchange Server 2007.  Data was migrated across from the old server before it was retired.

We now need to restore a folder from Public Folders from 9 months ago, from a tape backup using Symantec BackupExec.

How do I restore a public folder from a backup of Exchange 2003 into Exchange 2007?  Is this even technically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restore a 2003 database of any kind (mailbox or public folder) onto a 2007 server. Your options:

1. grab a spare box, install 2003, restore the db there, connect to the PFs with a mailbox and copy the data out to PST file(s) and then copy them into the PFs on the new box
2. use a db recovery package like http://www.ontrackpowercontrols.com/solutions/exchange-email-recovery/ to separately mount and extract the data from the restored .edb file.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's no such thing as an upgrade from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2007, so could you give us more details on your environment? How did you migrate\transition to Exchange 2007?

Comment: I have clarified my question.